# Boundedness of $m$-dissipative operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

When I was reading about unbounded operator I found that every m-dissipative operator has closed graph so by closed graph theorem this operator is bounded as we work in Banach space, I am confused because we were studying the unbounded operator, any help, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed graph theorem states if the domain of an operator $A:D(A)\subset X\to X$ is the Banach space $X$, then it is bounded. i.e., $X=D(A)$ implies the boundedness of $A$. That is, an everywhere defined closed operator is bounded. However, in the general case, $D(A)\neq X$. Not all closed operators are **everywhere defined**. For example, let us take $A:=\Delta$ with domain $D(A):=H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)$ is an m-dissipative operator in $L^2(\Omega)$. This operator is not bounded.

Comment: Thank you very much Ice sea , i still have a sub-question which is :as this operator m-dissipative so he has a closed graph , his domain is banach space as closed sub-space from banach space , shall this operator be m-dissipative and closed in this new banach space which is his domain??

Comment: Sorry, please state your question clear. I'm a bit of confuse about what you are talking. Please notice that m-dissipative operator has to map from a space into itself. The domain $Y:=D(A)$ under graph norm is a Banach space. But $A(Y)$ does not necessarily belong to $Y$.